# Jinja2 variables in included template

Tags: python, jinja2

I have parent template where settings variable and this template includes couple of other sub-templates where I want to reuse this variable. Unfortunately in children templates this variable is empty. How to fix it?

```
<!-- index.html -->
{%- set title= ' :: '.join((caption, page_title or '')) -%}
{%- set description= ' :: '.join((desc, meta_desc or '')) -%}
{%- block page_header -%}
  {% include 'parts/_header.html' %}

  <!-- I also tried do it with context without luck -->
  {% include 'parts/_header.html' %}
{%- endblock page_header -%}



<!-- parts/header.html -->
<header class="header-wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="title"><h1 class="title">{{ title|safe }}</h1></div>
    <div class="description">{{ description|safe }}</div>
  </div>
</header>
```

**UPD:** After small research I found that issue related to `{% block %}` section - in `include` tag is outside `block` then it is provided with document context. But for some reasons I'd like to keep it inside `block`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, this can be fixed by including your `{% set %}` declarations inside the `{% block %}` declarations.  In your example:

```
<!-- index.html -->
{%- block page_header -%}
  {%- set title= ' :: '.join((caption, page_title or '')) -%}
  {%- set description= ' :: '.join((desc, meta_desc or '')) -%}
  {% include 'parts/_header.html' %}
{%- endblock page_header -%}
```

If you need to set the same variables outside the block, I would just put the same line twice, once outside the block and once inside.  This seems imperfect to me, but I don't know another way.

Comment: Hmm, nice solution! I cannot check it right now, but it could be helpful for future use.